# Serialize nested structures with Gson

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am splitting my head with the following problem.
We have a service which returns following:

```
"err": {
    "IoTMessageServiceImpl": {
        "Connection lost": 1,
        "Could not reconnect client": 9
    },
    "Messaging": {
        "Message not sent: Client is not connected": 1
    }
}
```

Basically, this is an object *err* which contains a list of nested maps.
The key and value of the elements of IoTMessageServiceImpl and Messaging are variable. So I know I should create two objects called IoTMessageServiceImpl and Messaging which have a list of maps. However, I cannot get this structure in Java in the correct way. The closest I have come gave me the following output:

```
"err": {
    "IoTMessageServiceImpl": {
        "IoTMessageServiceImpl": [null,null]
    },
    "Messaging": {
        "message": [null]
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I should construct my classes to get the correct output with Gson?
Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: You want a java class to map this gson?

Comment: It is map of maps.. class err { HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> IoTMessageServiceImpl; HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> Messaging; }

Comment: Using that class structure, I am getting the following:  "err": {
  "IoTMessageServiceImpl": {
   "IoTMessageServiceImpl": {
    "Could not reconnect client": 9
   }
  },
  "Messaging": {
   "Messaging": {
    "Message not sent: Client is not connected": 1
   }
  }
 }

Comment: class err { HashMap<String, String> IoTMessageServiceImpl; HashMap<String, String> Messaging; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following, fixed it.
Thanks for leading me the right way @Uttam

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> IoTMessageServiceImpl;
private HashMap<String, Integer> Messaging;
```

Answer (score 1):

{
    "Connection lost": 1,
    "Could not reconnect client": 9
}

and

{
    "Message not sent: Client is not connected": 1
}

are not list of map.
They are map.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
class ErrorDTO {
    private IoTMessageServiceImplDTO IoTMessageServiceImpl;
    private MessagingDTO messaging;
}


class IoTMessageServiceImplDTO {
    ArrayList<String> IoTMessageServiceImpl;
}

class MessagingDTO {
    ArrayList<String> IoTMessageServiceImpl;
}
```